# How to remove dbContext command using NUGET?

Tags: c#, sql-server, model-view-controller, nuget

I have written this command on my NUGET console.
`Scaffold-DbContext "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=eNtsaRegistration;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models`. Basically i want to have new table definition on MVC web app project under Models folder. How can i achieve such? i am been struggling to get relevant information on this, please assist me mates?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you're using the Database First approach.

You can delete the files in the Models folder generated by EF Core and relaunching the same command.

Comment: i have relaunching using the same command, still no luck. Bear in mind all required Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer do exist still getting the above screen shot error.

Comment: Try running this command : > dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=eNtsaRegistration;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models

Comment: i am now getting this error when running this command. "  * You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
  * You intended to execute a .NET Core program, but dotnet-ef does not exist.
  * You intended to r
un a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH."

Comment: Run this command to install Entity Framework Core then run the first command : 
`dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 3.0.0`

Comment: Hi Mate i followed these steps, still no luck when i try to execute this command. Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
Package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.3.1.3' already exists in project 'eNtsaRegistrationTraining'
Time Elapsed: 00:00:00.0502252